# MySQL How to get user's activities?

Tags: mysql

i have sql tables like this and i want to show activities of the User in the User page and i dont know how to Write query about this so my table is look like this :

```
users
 id
 name

posts
 id
 title
 description

posts_likes
 id
 post_id
 user_id
 time

posts_comments
 id
 post_id
 user_id
 time
```

now i want to show users , thier activities in their page like : 
**you are commented on this post** 
OR
**you liked and commented on this post** 
 order by time so i write some query like this but it have a lots of problems...

```
SELECT posts.id , posts.title , posts_comments.comment , posts_likes.time , posts_comments.time
FROM posts 
JOIN posts_likes ON posts.id=posts_likes.post_id
JOIN posts_comments ON posts.id=posts_comments.post_id
WHERE posts_likes.user_id = 6 AND posts_comments.user_id =6
ORDER BY posts_likes.time, posts_comments.time DESC
```

so when i use this query it **brings me posts** that user with id = 6 **commented and liked** and never show me the posts that **user only commented** or **user only liked** , so if any body know how i can fix this problem i really appreciate thanks alot guys ... ***sry for my english***

Comment: add a 'log' table for it. any other option will be slower.

Comment: so u mean i should make another table and when user commented or liked any post fill the database?

Comment: You could try to change the AND in your where clause to an OR. You could also merge your posts_likes and posts_comments table and add a boolean column, when it's true it's a comment, when it's false it's a like.

Comment: @AliShafiee yes, as the DB became larger and you will found yourself on performance problems.

Comment: Guys what about UNION clause ?

Comment: @MosheL im agree with u but right now i should fix my problem this way ... tnx man for ur tip

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
SELECT posts.id , posts.title , posts_comments.comment , posts_likes.time , posts_comments.time
FROM posts 
LEFT JOIN posts_likes ON posts.id=posts_likes.post_id AND posts_likes.user_id = 6
LEFT JOIN posts_comments ON posts.id=posts_comments.post_id AND posts_comments.user_id = 6
WHERE  1
ORDER BY posts_likes.time DESC, posts_comments.time DESC
```

Untested

Comment: tnx man it is a good way to seprate them but its give me lots of record that i dont need and in big project make the proccessing slow i need it gives only the records...